# System.InvalidOperationException: No suitable constructor found for entity type 'BoundingBox'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using asp.net core 3.1 with entity framework core cosmos db provider. In my model I've a property for LocationCoordinates of type pointer. When checking if user exists I'm getting error.

I'm using point class in my model class ApplicationUser. Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Spatial.Point for saving coordinates latitude & longitude.

CosmosDb Package I'm using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos/

Please help.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Spatial;

namespace TestApp_Backend_API.Entities
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string ZipCode { get; set; }

        public Point LocationCoordinates { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using TestApp_Backend_API.Entities;

namespace TestApp_Backend_API.DbContexts
{
    public class TestAppContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public TestAppContext(DbContextOptions options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.HasDefaultContainer("Users");
            builder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToContainer("Users");
            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToContainer("Users");
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().ToContainer("UserRoles");
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().ToContainer("UserLogins");
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>().ToContainer("UserClaims");
            builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToContainer("Roles");
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>().ToContainer("UserTokens");
        }
    }
}
```

Calling this method giving error:

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
```

Error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No suitable constructor found for entity type 'BoundingBox'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'min', 'max' in 'BoundingBox(Position min, Position max)'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.ConstructorBindingConvention.ProcessModelFinalized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder, IConventionContext`1 context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelFinalized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnModelFinalized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model.FinalizeModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.FinalizeModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_3(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Set[TEntity]()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9.get_UsersSet()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9.get_Users()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9.FindByEmailAsync(String normalizedEmail, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.FindByEmailAsync(String email)
   at TestApp_Backend_API.Services.AuthRepository.IsEmailExistsAsync(String email) in D:\Ali\Projects\TestApp-Backend\TestApp-BackendServices\TestApp-Backend-API\Services\AuthRepository.cs:line 303
   at TestApp_Backend_API.Controllers.AuthController.SendEmailVerificationToken(SendEmailVerificationTokenDto dto) in D:\Ali\Projects\TestApp-Backend\TestApp-BackendServices\TestApp-Backend-API\Controllers\AuthController.cs:line 317
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Logged|12_1(ControllerActionInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Please see https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/15896 and https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/14336.

Comment: Can you please give the solution.

Comment: I'm using asp.net core 3.1

Comment: I think you can't use a Point in a cosmosDB entity only use plain object.

Answer (score 2):

- You're using Entity Framework Core (EF Core 3?) with CosmosDB.
- And you want to use CosmosDB's own spatial-types with EF Core.
- However as of late 2021 that [is still not supported by EF Core](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17317).
- As a workaround:

  - Change your use of spatial types to be computed properties, not stored properties, and use `[NotMapped]` so EF won't try to bind them.
  - You'll still need to store the raw values somewhere.

Like so:

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string ZipCode { get; set; }

        public double Latitude  { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public Point LocationCoordinates
        {
            get => new Point( this.Latitude, this.Longitude );
            set
            {
                this.Latitude  = value.Position.Latitude;
                this.Longitude = value.Position.Longitude;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. in my case, am trying to use Polygon. it will be like this 
{
 "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [54.87572265625,74.0013854318592],
        [53.59130859375,73.62159408606237],
        [53.96484375,73.16953636227885],
        [55.986328125, 73.59679245247814]]]} how do i save this?

Comment: @RanadheerReddy CosmosDB does support array types, however I don't know to what extent that EF Core 3.x supports it. Otherwise, to be safe, I'd just store it as a serialized string.

Comment: thanks. that will be better and easy. Please can you clarify one thing. If these spatial-types are not supported, what is this article about ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-geospatial-intro

Comment: @RanadheerReddy That article refers to using CosmosDB's geospatial types when you use CosmosDB's client library _directly_ without going through Entity Framework. EF is a very high-level abstraction over different data-sources and all abstractions necessarily mean compromising something, and in EF's case they compromised support for database-specific types (though EF does support SQL Server's geospatial types directly, that's only because they special-cased it). Or in other words: you don't need to use EF to use CosmosDB.

Comment: @RanadheerReddy I've suggested the article be improved to mention CosmosDB's own complex-types (like `Point` and `Polygon`) are not necessarily compatible with ORMs like EF Core: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/84374

Comment: that would be great if this clarification is provided in article. thank you very much for taking that initiative.

Comment: @RanadheerReddy An upvote would be appreciated in exchange for my initiative-taking ;)

Answer (score -1):

Create a private parameter less constructor for `BoundingBox`.

Comment: I've changed my answer.

Comment: In ApplicationUser class ?

Comment: in `BoundingBox` class.

Comment: But i don't have any BoundingBox class.

Comment: As your exception's message, you have one.

Comment: I'm using point class in my model. Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Spatial.Point for saving coordinates latitude & longitude.

Comment: Mehrdad Can you please help.

Comment: Don't use point because that is not suitable as a CosmosDB entity.